# highcharts - onclick event handlers redraw/remove

Tags: events, highcharts, onclick

Currently I have 4 charts. The selection (via column or legend) of a category from the main one triggers multiple events. It changes the selected item's color on two charts and it creates two more charts.

For the two created charts, I'm having problems with redrawing/removing (that is what I'm assuming I will have to do) when the column/legend is deselected.

I may be wrong but from what I've looked at, it seems that when you prevent show/hide it doesn't change the visibility property so I wasn't sure if there was a way to use that.

Any help would be appreciated!

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jlm578/gy9og69r/4/

I also thought about whether I needed to add it into the logic of the function (possibly one below) or if the sibling aspect needed to be added to the others.

```
function drawSignifNonSignifEruptionsChart(series){

if (series.index == '0'){
    var eruptVEI = ['VEI 0'];
    var signifErupt = [10];
    var nonSignifErupt = [600];

}
```

Comment: To update data of a chart you could use [`Series.setData`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData) and when you want to hide a chart you could hide it's container ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zmvauats/1/)).

Comment: So I modified by original plan and displayed a Signif/Non-Signif Eruptions chart on load. I am also able to with setData to change the chart onClick. However, when the user clicks the item again, I can't get it to reset back to the original data. Thoughts/examples? Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jlm578/gy9og69r/6/

Comment: If all points are black you should set default data back. Check what kind of point change is performed and change data in linked chart then instead of always setting data from clicked series.